# Why the energy of a state increases with increasing azimuthal quantum number $\ell$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals

I am reading Griffiths' introduction to quantum mechanics. But I am confused about the relation between the state energy and azimuthal quantum number $\ell$, which is discussed in Chapter 5.2.2 where the periodic table is introduced.

In the book, it is said that for $\rm He$ with the main quantum number $n$ as 2, the effect of electron repulsion is to favor the lowest value of $\ell$ which equals to 0; It is because the expectation value of $r$ (I suppose $r$ is the radius of orbit of electron to be discussed) increases with increasing $\ell$, which is to say that angular momentum tends to throw the electron outward. Within a given shell, therefore, the state with lowest energy is $\ell=0$, and the energy increases with increasing $\ell$.

However, I think that, with a larger $r$, the distance between outer and inner shells electrons will be larger, and hence the energy due to electron repulsion would be smaller. By this way, I think it means that with a larger $\ell$, the state would have a lower energy, which is a contradictory to the statement in the book.

So I would like to know where I made the mistake. By the way, in the book, it also mentions the screening effect. But I didn't see how screening effect could affect the interaction between electrons.

Comment: The only answer is in terms of the Hamiltonian's eigenvalues. If you look at the eigenvalues, do you see the dependence on $\ell$?

Comment: @RichardMyers I think the eigenvalues only depend on the main quantum number $n$.

Comment: Look at chapter 4 in the information on the hydrogen atom. The Hamiltonian has an $L^2$ term coming from the Laplacian written in spherical coordinates. The action of the Hamiltonian on simultaneous $n$ and $\ell$ eigenstates will thus have an $\ell$ dependence in their energy. This dependence is often wrapped up in what's called the "effective" potential.

Comment: @RichardMyers Thank you. I was also thinking that the potential will be changed with a larger $r$. Indeed, there is a centrifugal term in the effective potential involving $\ell$ in the Hamiltonian.